# How to again call the Api in react if data in store is old

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Case we check the object already exist in the store. How we can check if data updated in the backend.

Comment: Please provide me more details and also add code

Comment: Do you use redux?

Answer (score 1):

Please check react.memo in the new react hooks can solve this problem.